# SQLException in Hibernate: ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to modify a dao method with a distinct count on a column: 
I had:

```
    Criteria crit = statelessSession.createCriteria(APRecord.class, "apr");
    crit.createAlias("mAId", "mId", Criteria.INNER_JOIN);
    crit.addOrder( Order.asc("pName") );
    crit.addOrder( Order.asc("kNum") );
    return crit.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
```

I tried adding:

```
    crit.addOrder( Order.asc("pName") );
    crit.addOrder( Order.asc("kNum") );
    crit.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("agentG")));
```

but this gives me a SQL Exception:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT

Anyone know what the error is? Any help appreciated

Update:

fixed it by doing this:

```
    crit.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("pName"), "pName")
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("kNum"), "kNum")
            .add(Projections.countDistinct("agentG"), "count"));
```

but getting this error:

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to test.model.AR.APRecord
```

Comment: Can you post the sql query

Comment: And the reason is you have used a column in `Order by` clause which is not present in `select distinct` list

Comment: @Indian Please see the update